# Paypal - The link you have used to enter the PayPal system contains an incorrectly formatted item amount

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I know this type of question asked before but my issue is slightly different.

I am using paypal standard version, and I want to pass multiple items with discounts, below is my code, for discount I have used negative values.

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?
business=abc-facilitator%40gmail.com
item_name_0=Vancouver
amount_0=1799.00
item_name_1=Ottawa
amount_1=1799.00
item_name_2=Other
amount_2=1199.00
item_name_3=ppc+Verify+Facility
amount_3=599.00
item_name_4=Discount
amount_4=-2158.40
cmd=_cart
upload=1
no_note=1
lc=UK
currency_code=USD
bn=PP-BuyNowBF%3Abtn_buynow_LG.gif%3ANonHostedGuest
shipping=0.00
submit=Confirm+
return=http//:205.134.251.196/~examin8/CI/ppc/cart/paypal_procces/45
cancel_return=http//:205.134.251.196/~examin8/CI/ppc/cart/paypal_cancle/45
notify_url=http//:205.134.251.196/~examin8/CI/ppc/cart/paypal_procces/45
```

> **Error -  The link you have used to enter the PayPal system contains an**
>   **incorrectly formatted item amount.**

Comment: How is your question different from the others?

Comment: Because it's all parameter is correct, as I saw in other post users are doing currency code error, doing wrong in amount format that all are correct in my code, I am just trying to add discount.If I remove discount then it will work properly.

Comment: remove 'submit=Confirm+' from your code and then send code in paypal. because there is no any 'submit' params in paypal params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct code should be as below:

```html
item_name_1=Vancouver
amount_1=1799.00
item_name_2=Ottawa
amount_2=1799.00
item_name_3=Other
amount_3=1199.00
item_name_4=ppc+Verify+Facility
amount_4=599.00
discount_amount_cart=2158.40
cmd=_cart
upload=1
```

Refer to https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/cart_upload/